# Is there a way to create a date column from other columns?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

As the title says, can I create a new column from two fields? For example, I created a new column from the master values table to represent the months, and I have another column with the year. Can I combine them to create a date with whatever day? What I have is on the left, what I want is on the right:

```
Month    Year                            NewDate
----     ----                            -------
 3       2015                            2015-03-01
 4       2015                            2015-04-01
```

Whenever I tried to cast the month as datetime, it would look like this:

```
1900-01-03
```

This is probably a dumb question, but I created a timeline that lists out the months, and the trouble lies whenever the end date parameter chosen is less than the start date parameter, such as December 2015 to January 2016. I created the report in SSRS and the parameters aren't quite working correctly. Thanks guys!
Also, here's a snapshot of what the timeline looks like:

[image]

Comment: you can concatenate both column like `Year + '-' +  Month + '-' + '01'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select dateadd(mm, t.Month -1, dateadd(yy,t.Year-1900,'19000101'))
from table1 t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  DATEFROMPARTS ( [Year], [Month], 1 ) AS NewDate
FROM
  YourTable
;
```

Comment: I didn't know that function, still using SQL Server 2005 :(

Comment: I didn't for a while either, but then got spoiled by a BI tool that had something like that built in. By the time I needed it in SQL Server (2012), I looked for it and got lucky. As you pointed out, though, your mileage will vary by version.